# Birds Eye View using Bing Maps API (python)

Tags: python, google-maps, bing-maps, bing-api

I am hoping to fetch images of locations using BirdsEye (BE) view through Bing Maps API (using Python 3.x). Unfortunately I was unable to find any relevant documentation for BE view on the BING API site. Also there is a conflicting information on whether BirdsEye is included in the latest version of the Maps API.

2 questions:

1) Does anyone know or can point to good examples of accessing BirdsEye view using Python through Bing Maps API?

2) Alternatively, could you let me know how I can amend the below code to access the required BE view pictures of the selected location (in this case Bellevue Washington):

```
url = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/BirdsEye/Bellevue%20Washington?&key=" + bingMapsKey
print(url)
filename = 'maps_default.png'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
I = misc.imread(filename)
plt.imshow(I)
plt.show()
```

I found a similar question asked in 2012 without any relevant answers, so hoping someone else can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bing Maps birds eye images are not available outside of the Bing Maps interactive map controls. The static REST API does not provide access to these images. You will see in the documentation that birdseye is not listed as an imagery type for this service: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx